# How does one get recent media of user's follows sorted by date in instagram api?

Tags: instagram-api

It could be done over several requests in following algorithm:

1. Get user's follows `GET/users/user-id/follows`
2. Get each follows recent media by looping through follows list `GET/users/user-id/media/recent`

It would result in such a feed: first follow's recent media, then 2nd follow's recent media, etc. While desired result is the feed to be sorted by date. Just like it was done in instagram mobile app's home page

I could of course accumulate all the response and then programmatically parse each response, sort by date. But I was wondering if it is possible to do it with endpoint requests